# Rest assured + properties baseURI cannot be null class not loaded

Tags: java, json, api, rest, rest-assured

I have ConfigProperties.class

```
public class ConfigProperties {

@BeforeTest
public void TestDataSetup() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File src = new File("src\\main\\resources\\config.properties");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        ConfigProperties properties = new ConfigProperties();
        properties.load(fis);
    }

public void load(FileInputStream fis) {
}
}
```

below test method

```
public class Paragraphs extends ConfigProperties {

Properties prop = new Properties();


public void createParagraph() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("paragraphsURL");
```

here is config.properties

```
paragraphsURL=http://192.168.0.139:8880/paragraphs
```

After running my test I received error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseURI cannot be null
```

After debugging I have

```
RestAssured.baseURI = Class not loaded : io.restassured.RestAssured
```

Comment: are you certain your `prop.getProperty("paragraphsURL")` call returns any data? Why don't you debug or print it out

Comment: After debugging
RestAssured.baseURI = Class not loaded : io.restassured.RestAssured

Comment: So I'd suggest you dig into this a bit and rephrase the question

Comment: @LIvanov maybe any tip? I'm searching something about this in chrome but there is nothing.

Comment: Ok I did it. Below my code:

String propertiesFileName = "config.properties";
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName); {
        try {
            prop.load(resourceStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: this is the answer or an edit to the question ?